# I'm getting an error while using torchvision.datasets.Kinetics

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I’m trying to use [torchvision.datasets.Kinetics][1] but I’m getting this Assertion Error.

This is the initialization of the dataset

```
test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.Kinetics(root=root_path, frames_per_clip=33,
     step_between_clips=5, num_workers = 40, split='test', transform = transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size=224))
```

This is error I get:

```
AssertionError: Caught AssertionError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bairouk/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 287, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/home/bairouk/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 49, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/bairouk/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 49, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/bairouk/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/kinetics.py", line 234, in __getitem__
    video, audio, info, video_idx = self.video_clips.get_clip(idx)
  File "/home/bairouk/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/video_utils.py", line 373, in get_clip
    assert len(video) == self.num_frames, f"{video.shape} x {self.num_frames}"
AssertionError: torch.Size([34, 720, 1280, 3]) x 33
```

Thank you.
[1]: https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.Kinetics.html

Comment: Did you previously download the dataset with a different `frames_per_clip`?

Comment: no that's the only one I used, and I've never set any value of 34 in my code